# Ambari 2.7.5 installation failure on CentOS 7

Tags: java, maven, centos7, ambari

I am installing Apache Ambari 2.7.5 on a CentOS 7 machine.

I am following [the installation guide from the Apache website](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Installation+Guide+for+Ambari+2.7.5).

The last command of Step 1 of the guide

> mvn -B clean install rpm:rpm -DnewVersion=2.7.5.0.0 -DbuildNumber=5895e4ed6b30a2da8a90fee2403b6cab91d19972 -DskipTests -Dpython.ver="python >= 2.6" -e

ends with the following error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:18 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-30T22:51:27+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (Bower install) on project ambari-admin: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (Bower install) on project ambari-admin: Command execution failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command execution failed.
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:377)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:160)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:610)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:352)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :ambari-admin
```

The Maven version I have is 3.6.3, Java version is 1.8.0_252.

The error description does not look very informative to me. The help link provided at the end of the error stack is not very helpful either: it says that "unlike many other errors, this exception is not generated by the Maven core itself but by a plugin. As a rule of thumb, plugins use this error to signal a problem in their configuration or the information they retrieved from the POM."

I don't have much experience with Maven, so I am feeling stuck at this point. Does anybody have any idea where to move from here? Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: I am working on the same thing.  I have successfully built from source before many times, but right now im having issues that seem to be related to x64 technology in my local workstation and the cloud service I use.   Reference this link:  https://nbhat-technical.blogspot.com/2018/08/apache-ambari-on-arm64.html. I still l have not been able to get it to build, and fails with similar errors.

Comment: after -B you can add --fail-at-end   and it will build all the packages.  Your failure above is on "ambari-admin" out of the list of all packages.

Comment: The only workaround I found is to set up Ambari from Cloudera repo (https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari/Ambari-2.7.4.0/index.html). The version 2.7.5 requires active Cloudera subscription, but 2.7.4 is available for free. The problem described in my question didn't appear in the Cloudera package.

Comment: Yah no problem with doing that... however im working on building from source, and building my own Data Platform,  ie without HDP/HDF/CDx...

Comment: Another stack member helped me resolve the issue I had building Ambari From Source.

Comment: Did this issue resolve i am facing the same issue

Answer (score 7):

@KonstantinPopov

For the MojoExecutionException errors you are having above,  you need to do some additional work inside of your build environment.  If you follow the directions exactly, you still have to get correct versions of maven, npm, and nodejs before building the ambari packages with the ambari mvn commands.  Also in ambari-admin pom.xml you need to set the versions for Node/NPM. Then it should build correctly.

My full history for Centos 7.4 is as follows:

```
[root@c7401 apache-ambari-2.7.5-src]# history
    1  yum install wget rsync nano maven java java-devel rpm-build gcc -y
    2  yum install ntp python python-devel rpm-build gcc-c++ java-1.7.0-openjdk java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel git -y
    3  wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg#md5=fe1f997bc722265116870bc7919059ea
    4  sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
    5  wget https://downloads.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.6.3/binaries/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.tar.gz -P /tmp
    6  tar xf /tmp/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.tar.gz -C /opt
    7  ln -s /opt/apache-maven-3.6.3 /opt/maven
    8  nano /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
    9  chmod +x /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
   10  source /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
   11  mvn -v
   15  wget https://downloads.apache.org/ambari/ambari-2.7.5/apache-ambari-2.7.5-src.tar.gz
   16  tar xfvz apache-ambari-2.7.5-src.tar.gz
   17  cd apache-ambari-2.7.5-src
   19  cd ambari-admin
   28  yum --enablerepo=extras install epel-release
   29  yum install npm -y
   32  node -v
   33  npm -v
   34  nano pom.xml
   35  cd ..
   36  mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=2.7.5.0.0
   37  pushd ambari-metrics
   38  mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=2.7.5.0.0
   39  popd
   40  mvn -B clean install rpm:rpm -DnewVersion=2.7.5.0.0 -DbuildNumber=5895e4ed6b30a2da8a90fee2403b6cab91d19972 -DskipTests -Dpython.ver="python >= 2.7"
   41  yum install /root/apache-ambari-2.7.5-src/ambari-server/target/rpm/ambari-server/RPMS/x86_64/ambari-server-2.7.5.0-0.x86_64.rpm
   42  yum install /root/apache-ambari-2.7.5-src/ambari-agent/target/rpm/ambari-agent/RPMS/x86_64/ambari-agent-2.7.5.0-0.x86_64.rpm
```

Contents of maven file:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-openjdk
export M2_HOME=/opt/maven
export MAVEN_HOME=/opt/maven
export PATH=${M2_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```

Change in Ambari Admin Pom File: (Make sure your versions are correct)

```
           <configuration>
              <nodeVersion>v6.17.1</nodeVersion>
              <npmVersion>3.10.10</npmVersion>
              <workingDirectory>src/main/resources/ui/admin-web/</workingDirectory> 
<npmInheritsProxyConfigFromMaven>false</npmInheritsProxyConfigFromMaven>
            </configuration>
```

Comment: Java 7 (and 8) is EOL. I would expect it to build fine with Java 11

Comment: @steven-matison I followed the steps as you have mentioned.. But my installation failed .103666 error Linux 4.14.219-161.340.amzn2.x86_64
103667 error argv "/home/ec2-user/apache-ambari-2.7.5-src/ambari-admin/src/main/resources/ui/admin-web/node/node" "/home/ec2-user/apache-ambari-2.7.5-src/ambari-admin/src/main/resources/ui/admin-web/node/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "install" "--unsafe-perm"
103668 error node v6.17.1
103669 error npm  v3.10.10