# Ambari Admin View 2.7.5.0.0 build failure

Tags: java, node.js, maven, npm, ambari

I am trying to build Ambari RPM from source code. After running this command I am getting error as stated below

**mvn -B clean install rpm:rpm -DnewVersion=2.7.5.0.0 -DbuildNumber=5895e4ed6b30a2da8a90fee2403b6cab91d19972 -DskipTests -Dpython.ver="python >= 2.6"**

Error:

```
[WARNING] npm WARN package.json adminconsole@0.0.0 No description
[WARNING] npm WARN package.json adminconsole@0.0.0 No repository field.
[WARNING] npm WARN package.json adminconsole@0.0.0 No README data
[WARNING] npm WARN package.json adminconsole@0.0.0 No license field.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (Bower install) @ ambari-admin ---
bower                            error Unexpected token {

Stack trace:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/apache-ambari-2.7.5-src/ambari-admin/src/main/resources/ui/admin-web/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-registry-client/node_modules/request/lib/cookies.js:3:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)

Console trace:
Trace
    at StandardRenderer.error (/root/apache-ambari-2.7.5-src/ambari-admin/src/main/resources/ui/admin-web/node_modules/bower/lib/renderers/StandardRenderer.js:72:17)
    at Logger.<anonymous> (/root/apache-ambari-2.7.5-src/ambari-admin/src/main/resources/ui/admin-web/node_modules/bower/bin/bower:111:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Logger.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Logger.emit (/root/apache-ambari-2.7.5-src/ambari-admin/src/main/resources/ui/admin-web/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-logger/lib/Logger.js:29:39)
    at /root/apache-ambari-2.7.5-src/ambari-admin/src/main/resources/ui/admin-web/node_modules/bower/lib/commands/index.js:40:20
    at _rejected (/root/apache-ambari-2.7.5-src/ambari-admin/src/main/resources/ui/admin-web/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:797:24)
    at /root/apache-ambari-2.7.5-src/ambari-admin/src/main/resources/ui/admin-web/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:823:30
    at Promise.when (/root/apache-ambari-2.7.5-src/ambari-admin/src/main/resources/ui/admin-web/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:1035:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/root/apache-ambari-2.7.5-src/ambari-admin/src/main/resources/ui/admin-web/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:741:41)

System info:
Bower version: 1.3.8
Node version: 4.5.0
OS: Linux 3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64 x64
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Ambari Main 2.7.5.0.0 .............................. SUCCESS [  3.564 s]
[INFO] Apache Ambari Project POM 2.7.5.0.0 ................ SUCCESS [  0.182 s]
[INFO] Ambari Web 2.7.5.0.0 ............................... SUCCESS [ 59.879 s]
[INFO] Ambari Views 2.7.5.0.0 ............................. SUCCESS [  1.327 s]
[INFO] Ambari Admin View 2.7.5.0.0 ........................ FAILURE [  4.946 s]
[INFO] ambari-utility 1.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ambari-metrics 2.7.5.0.0 ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Common 2.7.5.0.0 .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Hadoop Sink 2.7.5.0.0 ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Flume Sink 2.7.5.0.0 ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Kafka Sink 2.7.5.0.0 ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Storm Sink 2.7.5.0.0 ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Storm Sink (Legacy) 2.7.5.0.0 ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Collector 2.7.5.0.0 ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Monitor 2.7.5.0.0 ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Grafana 2.7.5.0.0 ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Host Aggregator 2.7.5.0.0 ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Assembly 2.7.5.0.0 .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Service Advisor 1.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Server 2.7.5.0.0 ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Functional Tests 2.7.5.0.0 .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Agent 2.7.5.0.0 ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ambari-logsearch 2.7.5.0.0 ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Appender 2.7.5.0.0 ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Config Api 2.7.5.0.0 .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Config JSON 2.7.5.0.0 ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Config Solr 2.7.5.0.0 ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Config Zookeeper 2.7.5.0.0 ........ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Config Local 2.7.5.0.0 ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Log Feeder Plugin Api 2.7.5.0.0 ... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Log Feeder Container Registry 2.7.5.0.0 SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Log Feeder 2.7.5.0.0 .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Web 2.7.5.0.0 ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Server 2.7.5.0.0 .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Assembly 2.7.5.0.0 ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Integration Test 2.7.5.0.0 ........ SKIPPED
[INFO] ambari-infra 2.7.5.0.0 ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Infra Solr Client 2.7.5.0.0 ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Infra Solr Plugin 2.7.5.0.0 ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Infra Manager 2.7.5.0.0 ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Infra Assembly 2.7.5.0.0 .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Infra Manager Integration Tests 2.7.5.0.0 ... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:10 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-05-07T05:14:37-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (Bower install) on project ambari-admin: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :ambari-admin
```

pom.xml:
[pom.xml](https://hastebin.com/ezerujofez.xml)

So far I have tried to change the node version at this directory **ambari-admin/src/main/resources/ui/admin-web/node** by changing the node binary file

Comment: see this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61542102/ambari-2-7-5-installation-failure-on-centos-7?noredirect=1#comment109002945_61542102. and read my comments...

Comment: the steps I completed from the link I reference for x64 solution still fails with the same error you have above..  I am still trying to find solution.

Comment: @steven-dfheinz I have found the solution. you have to change the version of node and npm in pom file which you will find in ambari-admin directory

Comment: Nice one, thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have found the solution just by changing the node and npm version in ambari-admin directory.

Before

```
 <configuration>
      <nodeVersion>v4.5.0</nodeVersion>
      <npmVersion>2.15.0</npmVersion>
      <workingDirectory>src/main/resources/ui/admin-web/</workingDirectory>
      <npmInheritsProxyConfigFromMaven>false</npmInheritsProxyConfigFromMaven>
 </configuration>
```

After

```
  <configuration>
          <nodeVersion>v11.10.0</nodeVersion>
          <npmVersion>6.7.0</npmVersion>
          <workingDirectory>src/main/resources/ui/admin-web/</workingDirectory>
          <npmInheritsProxyConfigFromMaven>false</npmInheritsProxyConfigFromMaven>
   </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the above, I fixed the version of the bower. Here the details https://github.com/apache/bigtop/pull/628/files