# wget + download ambari tar ball

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, ambari, hdp, hortonworks-dataflow

we are trying to download the ambari version 2.6.1 but without success ( according to https://docs.hortonworks.com.s3.amazonaws.com/HDPDocuments/HDF3/HDF-3.1.1/bk_installing-hdf-on-hdp-p... )

```
wget http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos7-ppc/2.x/updates/2.6.1.0
--2021-02-16 14:44:08-- http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos7-ppc/2.x/updates/2.6.1.0
Resolving public-repo-1.hortonworks.com (public-repo-1.hortonworks.com)... 13.225.255.100, 13.225.255.128, 13.225.255.124, ...
Connecting to public-repo-1.hortonworks.com (public-repo-1.hortonworks.com)|13.225.255.100|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2021-02-16 14:44:09 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

any idea why we get `ERROR 403: Forbidden` ?

why we cant download ambari versions from hortonworks site ?

note - but we can download from other site as

```
wget http://archive.apache.org/dist/ambari/ambari-2.6.1/apache-ambari-2.6.1-src.tar.gz

--2021-02-16 14:41:07--  http://archive.apache.org/dist/ambari/ambari-2.6.1/apache-ambari-2.6.1-src.tar.gz
Resolving archive.apache.org (archive.apache.org)... 138.201.131.134, 2a01:4f8:172:2ec5::2
Connecting to archive.apache.org (archive.apache.org)|138.201.131.134|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 131359986 (125M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘apache-ambari-2.6.1-src.tar.gz’

100%[===================================================================================================================================================>] 131,359,986 12.6MB/s   in 10s
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is open version here: https://makeopensourcegreatagain.com/rpms/

There is stack thread about it: [How to build deb/rpm repos from open source Hadoop or publicly available HDP source code to be installed by ambari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61805789/how-to-build-deb-rpm-repos-from-open-source-hadoop-or-publicly-available-hdp-sou)

Comment: What's the support model of that repo? How are upgrades handled and issues reported?

Comment: I don't believe there is any consistent model. I don't see much activity there from the time it was created. But at this point, as free Hadoop products go, choice is severely limited.

Comment: Fair. I think Apache Bigtop project is semi-regularly updated.

Answer (score 3):

hortonworks/cloudera has closed their repos out, they are no longer offering binaries as of Jan 31st 2021 without a license/subscription.

Answer (score 1):

Ambari and HDP are still very coupled together. Even when you build ambari from source, HDP still exists in /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/stacks/. From the install wizard you have to provide a stack structure, telling ambari which versions to use. The HDP version of ambari from Hortonworks or Cloudera repos already includes HDP Stack.