# Maven version error while trying to install ambari on centos

Tags: maven, installation, centos7, ambari

I am trying to install ambari 2.7.5 on centos 7. I am following the instructions given on this [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Installation+Guide+for+Ambari+2.7.5). When I run the build command for maven I get the following error:

[image: Error]

I have installed maven 3.6.3 . And I could not find maven 3.1.0 in apache downloads. So how to resolve this error?

Comment: That looks more like that you have not installed Maven 3.6.3..the other issue could be that the frontend-maven-plugin is requiring a fixed version of Maven which I would say is a bug in frontend-maven-plugin

Answer (score 0):

@VK for Ambari-web you have to edit some files and set your versions.  If you are having hard time with npm/node version make sure they match the posted versions I gave.   In centos7 I am using the epel repository.  Sounds like you already got current maven so good to go there.

Also this post is pretty much a duplicate of:

[Building Ambari 2.7.5 on CentOS 7 from source, Worked 2 weeks ago, now fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62251610/building-ambari-2-7-5-on-centos-7-from-source-worked-2-weeks-ago-now-fails/62334756#62334756)

Its also discussed here:
[Ambari 2.7.5 installation failure on CentOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61542102/ambari-2-7-5-installation-failure-on-centos-7)

And a jira with another bower file sample:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMBARI-25519