# Ambari Web build fails with Error: Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.4:install-node-and-yarn

Tags: java, node.js, maven, npm, ambari

I followed the instructions on this post:

[Ambari 2.7.5 installation failure on CentOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61542102/ambari-2-7-5-installation-failure-on-centos-7)

Unfortunately, I am still getting an error:

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Ambari Main ....................................... SUCCESS [11:41.142s]
[INFO] Apache Ambari Project POM ......................... SUCCESS [0.173s]
[INFO] Ambari Web ........................................ FAILURE [33.222s]
[INFO] Ambari Views ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Admin View ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ambari-utility .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ambari-metrics .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Common ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Hadoop Sink ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Flume Sink ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Kafka Sink ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Storm Sink ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Storm Sink (Legacy) ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Collector .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Monitor ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Grafana ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Host Aggregator .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Assembly ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Service Advisor ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Server ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Functional Tests ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Agent ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ambari-logsearch .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Appender ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Config Api ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Config JSON ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Config Solr ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Config Zookeeper ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Config Local ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Log Feeder Plugin Api ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Log Feeder Container Registry .... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Log Feeder ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Web .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Server ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Assembly ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Logsearch Integration Test ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ambari-infra ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Infra Solr Client .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Infra Solr Plugin .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Infra Manager .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Infra Assembly ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Infra Manager Integration Tests ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12:15.037s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jun 08 10:27:49 UTC 2020
[INFO] Final Memory: 31M/381M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.4:install-node-and-yarn (install node and yarn) on project ambari-web: The plugin com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.4 requires Maven version 3.1.0 -> [Help 1]
```

UPDATE: Adding CentOS command history:

```
    1  sudo yum install wget rsync nano maven java java-devel rpm-build gcc -y
    2  sudo yum install ntp python python-devel rpm-build gcc-c++ java-1.7.0-openjdk java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel git -y
    3  sudo wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg#md5=fe1f997bc722265116870bc7919059ea
    4  sudo sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
    5  sudo wget https://downloads.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.6.3/binaries/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.tar.gz -P /tmp
    6  sudo tar xf /tmp/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.tar.gz -C /opt
    7  sudo ln -s /opt/apache-maven-3.6.3 /opt/maven
    8  sudo nano /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
    9  sudo chmod +x /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
   10  source /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
   11  mvn -v
   15  sudo wget https://downloads.apache.org/ambari/ambari-2.7.5/apache-ambari-2.7.5-src.tar.gz
   16  sudo tar xfvz apache-ambari-2.7.5-src.tar.gz
   17  cd apache-ambari-2.7.5-src
   19  cd ambari-admin
   28  sudo yum --enablerepo=extras install epel-release
   29  sudo yum install npm -y
   32  node -v
   33  npm -v
   34  sudo nano pom.xml
   35  cd ..
   36  sudo mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=2.7.5.0.0
   37  pushd ambari-metrics
   38  sudo mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=2.7.5.0.0
   39  popd
   40  sudo mvn -B clean install rpm:rpm -DnewVersion=2.7.5.0.0 -DbuildNumber=5895e4ed6b30a2da8a90fee2403b6cab91d19972 -DskipTests -Dpython.ver="python >= 2.7"
```

Here's my environment:
CentOS 7

NPM version:
3.10.10

Node version:
v6.17.1

Java version:
openjdk version "1.8.0_252"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_252-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.252-b09, mixed mode)

Maven version:
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /opt/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_252, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.252.b09-2.el7_8.x86_64/jre

Comment: Please update your post with the history of commands inside the centos7 instance so we can see what steps you took.

Comment: @steven-dfheinz  Updated. Added the command history.

Comment: Which centos version, and where is it from? For example my test was 7.3 and vagrant vm (from ambari quick start page).   Check your python version too?  The other difference I can see is the 1.7 vs 1.8 jdk,  which I would think 1.8 should still work...

Comment: This is an AWS AMI.     
Virtualization: kvm
  Operating System: CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
            Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-1127.10.1.el7.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64

Comment: Ok.  Thats a big difference.   The error is saying maven version isn't right in the execution.  In the commands up there are the commands to get maven.  I can see you completed them, but you may need adjust those steps for you environment.  Don't forget to check python version too.

Comment: I did try downgrading Maven versions to 3.1.0. It is still giving me the same error.

Comment: I threw in a --version in the clean install command to check which maven it's using. That maybe where the issue is because it is showing: Apache Maven 3.0.5 (Red Hat 3.0.5-17)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven

But when i do mvn-v, it shows:
Apache Maven 3.1.0 (893ca28a1da9d5f51ac03827af98bb730128f9f2; 2013-06-28 02:15:32+0000)
Maven home: /opt/maven

Where do I go to change the maven version being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dribble. While working on Ambari 2.7.5 for SUSE 12,  I ran into the same error.   You need to make sure to get maven version right first (Apache Maven 3.3.9 or later).

The specific package dependency errors are fixed by editing ambari-web/pom.xml and setting the node version to version installed in building operating system.

Once I did this, the build completed the Ambari Web Steps.  You may run into similar dependency failures with other packages.  You can see the following recent posts for more details including specific versions:

[Error building ambari 2.7.5 Centos 7 (fails at ambari-admin step)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62333719/error-building-ambari-2-7-5-centos-7-fails-at-ambari-admin-step)

Comment: I was able to get this working but now the build fails on the ambari-admin phase. 
 Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (Bower install) on project ambari-admin: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

Comment: The solution to handle ambari-admin is already linked above.