# Error building ambari 2.7.5 Centos 7 (fails at ambari-admin step)

Tags: build, centos, ambari

I am trying to build ambari 2.7.5 on Centos 7 per [these instructions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Installation+Guide+for+Ambari+2.7.5), which is relatively straightforward.

However, when the build gets to ambari-admin, it fails.   There are several posts out there that describe a supposed solution to this- which is editing "...ambari-admin/pom.xml" and setting the node and npm versions to match the versions installed on the server.

Sadly, this does not work for me.  And I have tried the versions of node/npm that come with Centos(EPEL), I have tried the LATEST node/npm versions from apache, and I've tried older versions.   I edit the pom.xml file to match.

In the end, it is always the exact same failure regardless of the dozens of attempts using the above.

```
mvn -B clean install rpm:rpm -DnewVersion=2.7.5.0.0 -DbuildNumber=5895e4ed6b30a2da8a90fee2403b6cab91d19972 -DskipTests -Dpython.ver="python >= 2.6"


[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 02:05 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-11T15:43:05-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 43M/2151M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (Bower install) on project ambari-admin: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (Bower install) on project ambari-admin: Command execution failed.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command execution failed.
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:377)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:160)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:610)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:352)
        ... 22 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :ambari-admin
```

Lastly, I've ALSO tried downgrading what I am building-  trying 2.7.4, 2.7.3,..   and same thing.

Clearly, it appears I am missing something basic but I have no idea what.

Here is the typical setup I do before executing the above mvn build command:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-openjdk
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven-3.3.9
export MAVEN_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven-3.3.9
export PATH=${M2_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.awt.headless=true"


# npm -v
3.10.10
# node -v
v6.17.1
# mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T10:41:47-06:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.8.0_252, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.252.b09-2.el7_8.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.10.0-1127.8.2.el7.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

cd /usr/local/src
wget https://www-eu.apache.org/dist/ambari/ambari-2.7.5/apache-ambari-2.7.5-src.tar.gz
tar xfvz apache-ambari-2.7.5-src.tar.gz
cd apache-ambari-2.7.5-src
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=2.7.5.0.0

pushd ambari-metrics
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=2.7.5.0.0
popd
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution you are looking for is to edit

```
ambari-admin/pom.xml
```

You will need to update your version of npm/node.   For example in my build today:

```
<nodeVersion>v10.21.0</nodeVersion>
<npmVersion>6.14.4</npmVersion>
```

Those versions are in the build and the build environment.  I had to go backwards from node14 to node 10 in order to get dependencies to work all way through to the next bower/angular conflict.

Depending on your build environment you may also need to edit

```
ambari-admin/src/main/resources/ui/admin-web/bower.json
```

For example in my build today:

```
{
  "name": "adminconsole",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "angular": "1.3.0",
    "angular-route": "1.3.0",
    "angular-bootstrap": "0.11.0",
    "underscore": "1.7.0",
    "restangular": "1.4.0",
    "angular-bootstrap-toggle-switch": "0.5.1",
    "angular-animate": "1.3.0",
    "angular-translate": "~2.8.1",
    "font-awesome": "4.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.3.0",
    "commonjs": "0.2.0",
    "chai": "1.8.0",
    "mocha": "1.14.0",
    "sinon": "1.10.3"
  }
}
```

You may also need to get maven 3.6.3:

```
    5 wget https://downloads.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.6.3/binaries/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.tar.gz -P /tmp
    6  tar xf /tmp/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.tar.gz -C /opt
    7  ln -s /opt/apache-maven-3.6.3 /opt/maven
    8  nano /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
    9  chmod +x /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
   10  source /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
   11  mvn -v
```

You can find more info on this post:

[Ambari 2.7.5 installation failure on CentOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61542102/ambari-2-7-5-installation-failure-on-centos-7)

Comment: Per my post:

I've already edited ambari-admin/pom.xml.   I changed the versions to match what is installed.

I am already using maven 3.6.3.

The post you directed me to:  I have done all of that verbatim.

The one final suggestion you made I have not tried--  editing the bower.json file.   I am interested, but what change, exactly, should I be making inthat file?

Comment: The code above was one later attempt using an older maven by the way.   I have also used the latest 3.6.3.   Made zero difference.

Comment: Your maven says Apache Maven 3.3.9.    The bower file comes into play when you an error that says "Unable to find suitable version for angular".   You need to continue to focus on right versions in pom.xml.    Im updating the answer above with version pair that works in my testing today.

Comment: BEAUTIFUL.   The magic sauce that's the showstopper here is the bower.json file and the angular versions.   I did not see any error at all complaining about not being able to find a suitable angular (or perhaps, maybe it did, but it grabbed a version not suitable after all?).     I put the angular versions in the bower.json file and the build is happening now.    Nowjere else did I find this info, so thank you so much.

For future reference, where exactly would I look to see the angular error about an unsuitable version not found?   Just curious.

Comment: Heck ya,  congrats!  I literally spent all day battling this for SUSE flavor that isn't done yet anywhere online,  got all my rpms built after countless attempts, and then started having issues in the ambari install... tomorrow is another day.    When the mvn build command fails, there is a limited error on bottom.  Then you scroll up and look for [ERROR]... sometimes I save the whole terminal output, and then search through it because it can be miles long...   I think the key is getting a stable combination of version + limited edits in the ambari src code...

Comment: I have some mpacks you might be interested in after you get ambari installed.   dfhz_hdp_mpack for HDP 3.1.4 w/o Hortonworks repos.   dfhz_ddp_mpack is a custom stack I am building now.  Both on my GitHub:  https://github.com/steven-dfheinz?tab=repositories