# Build Ambari 2.7.5 on Centos 7.8 from sources error

Tags: hadoop, ambari

I am following the guide :

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Installation+Guide+for+Ambari+2.7.5

and with this info
[Ambari 2.7.5 installation failure on CentOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61542102/ambari-2-7-5-installation-failure-on-centos-7)
, I managed to overcome the ambari-admin error, but now I am facing a new one :

```
[INFO] Ambari Main 2.7.5.0.0 .............................. SUCCESS [  2.950 s]
[INFO] Apache Ambari Project POM 2.7.5.0.0 ................ SUCCESS [  0.042 s]
[INFO] Ambari Web 2.7.5.0.0 ............................... SUCCESS [01:03 min]
[INFO] Ambari Views 2.7.5.0.0 ............................. SUCCESS [  1.323 s]
[INFO] Ambari Admin View 2.7.5.0.0 ........................ SUCCESS [  8.071 s]
[INFO] ambari-utility 1.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT .................... SUCCESS [  1.393 s]
[INFO] ambari-metrics 2.7.5.0.0 ........................... SUCCESS [  0.266 s]
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Common 2.7.5.0.0 .................... SUCCESS [  5.458 s]
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Hadoop Sink 2.7.5.0.0 ............... SUCCESS [  3.045 s]
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Flume Sink 2.7.5.0.0 ................ SUCCESS [  1.904 s]
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Kafka Sink 2.7.5.0.0 ................ SUCCESS [  1.897 s]
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Storm Sink 2.7.5.0.0 ................ SUCCESS [  2.106 s]
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Storm Sink (Legacy) 2.7.5.0.0 ....... SUCCESS [  2.369 s]
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Collector 2.7.5.0.0 ................. FAILURE [  0.164 s]
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Monitor 2.7.5.0.0 ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Grafana 2.7.5.0.0 ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Host Aggregator 2.7.5.0.0 ........... SKIPPED




[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project
   ambari-metrics-timelineservice: Could not resolve dependencies for
   project
   org.apache.ambari:ambari-metrics-timelineservice:jar:2.7.5.0.0: The
   following artifacts could not be resolved:
   org.apache.phoenix:phoenix-core:jar:5.0.0.3.1.4.0-315,
   org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:3.1.1.3.1.4.0-315,
   org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-annotations:jar:3.1.1.3.1.4.0-315,
   org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:tests:3.1.1.3.1.4.0-315,
   org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-common:jar:tests:3.1.1.3.1.4.0-315,
   org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-common:jar:3.1.1.3.1.4.0-315,
   org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-api:jar:3.1.1.3.1.4.0-315,
   org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-server-common:jar:3.1.1.3.1.4.0-315,
   org.apache.phoenix:phoenix-core:jar:tests:5.0.0.3.1.4.0-315,
   org.apache.hbase:hbase-testing-util:jar:2.0.2.3.1.4.0-315: Failure to
   find org.apache.phoenix:phoenix-core:jar:5.0.0.3.1.4.0-315 in
   https://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public/ was cached in the
   local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
   interval of apache-hadoop has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help
   1]
```

any suggestions please?

Comment: I believe `https://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public/` is protected now, or was moved by Cloudera. You'd have to refer to their installation documentation. https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.7.5.0/bk_ambari-installation/content/ch_Getting_Ready.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the error, the dependency chain includes at least

`org.apache.phoenix:phoenix-core:jar:5.0.0.3.1.4.0-315`, which is accessible at

https://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public/org/apache/phoenix/phoenix-core/

And there is no version `3.1.4.0-315` listed there, which will cause the build to fail without some other location where such packages exist, which I am not aware of any outside of the new Cloudera repo listed in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

seems to work. what I did : (replaced 0-315 version with 1-1)

apache-ambari-2.7.5-src/ambari-metrics

replace in pom.xml

:%s/0-315/1-1/g

apache-ambari-2.7.5-src/ambari-metrics/ambari-metrics-timelineservice

pom.xml

```
 <properties>
    <!-- Needed for generating FindBugs warnings using parent pom -->
    <!--<yarn.basedir>${project.parent.parent.basedir}</yarn.basedir>-->
    <protobuf.version>2.5.0</protobuf.version>
    <hadoop.version>3.1.1.3.1.4.1-1</hadoop.version>
    <phoenix.version>5.0.0.3.1.4.1-1</phoenix.version>
    <hbase.version>2.0.2.3.1.4.1-1</hbase.version>
  </properties>
```