# Build hadoop3.1.1 failed for CMake test failed on hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager

Tags: hadoop, cmake, build, hdp

I try to build hadoop (HDP3.1.5), the env versions is below:
hadoop version 3.1.1.3.1.4.0-315
cmake version 3.18.2
java version openjdk version "1.8.0_262"
maven version 3.6.3
CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003
github code https://github.com/hortonworks/hadoop-release 
tag is **HDP-3.1.4.0-315-tag** 
when i run 
mvn package -Pdist,native -Dtar -Dmaven.test.skip=true -e 
i get the error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:3.1.1.3.1.4.0-315:cmake-test (test-container-executor) on project hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager: Test /root/hadoop-release/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager/target/native/target/usr/local/bin/test-container-executor returned ERROR CODE 1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:3.1.1.3.1.4.0-315:cmake-test (test-container-executor) on project hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager: Test /root/hadoop-release/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager/target/native/target/usr/local/bin/test-container-executor returned ERROR CODE 1
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Test /root/hadoop-release/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager/target/native/target/usr/local/bin/test-container-executor returned ERROR CODE 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.maven.plugin.cmakebuilder.TestMojo.execute (TestMojo.java:386)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

*Is there something wrong with versions or other settings*

Answer (score 0):

@none you need to work from this doc (cluster w/o stack):

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Quick+Start+Guide

There are a few posts I have worked on that expose versions:

```
npm -v
    6.14.4
node -v
    v10.21.0
python -V
    Python 2.7.18
mvn -v
    Apache Maven 3.6.3
```

[Ambari 2.7.5 installation failure on CentOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61542102/ambari-2-7-5-installation-failure-on-centos-7)

[Build Ambari 2.7.5 on Centos 7.8 from sources error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63085657/build-ambari-2-7-5-on-centos-7-8-from-sources-error)

You can also build ambari 2.7.5 w/ HDP 3.1.5 from here:

https://github.com/steven-matison/dfhz_hdp_mpack

My last suggestion is to use the last public version from hortonworks/cloudera Ambari 2.7.4:

https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.7.4.0/bk_ambari-installation/content/ambari_repositories.html

Comment: thank you, i build ambari 2.7.5 has no hadoop.tar.gz and hbase, phoenix,hortworks repo can not download. then I try to build them , and i got the problem...hbase phoenix is ok.