# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) on project ambari-server: Compilation failure

Tags: java, maven, ambari, rhel8

Trying to install **Apache-Ambari** on **linux RHEL8** by running the following command:
**mvn -B clean install rpm:rpm -DnewVersion=2.7.6.0.0 -DbuildNumber=388e072381e71c7755673b7743531c03a4d61be8 -DskipTests -Dpython.ver="python >= 2.7"  -Drat.numUnapprovedLicenses=2000**

And I get the following error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:50 h
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-03-09T11:18:08+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) on project ambari-server: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/api/services/ComponentService.java:[41,37] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ApiIgnore
[ERROR]   location: package org.apache.ambari.annotations
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/api/services/AlertService.java:[32,37] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ApiIgnore
[ERROR]   location: package org.apache.ambari.annotations
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/api/services/AlertHistoryService.java:[32,37] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ApiIgnore
[ERROR]   location: package org.apache.ambari.annotations
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/api/services/LoggingService.java:[37,37] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ApiIgnore
[ERROR]   location: package org.apache.ambari.annotations
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/controller/internal/ViewInstanceResourceProvider.java:[50,30] package org.apache.ambari.view does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/controller/internal/ViewInstanceResourceProvider.java:[51,41] package org.apache.ambari.view.validation does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewInstanceEntity.java:[59,30] package org.apache.ambari.view does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewInstanceEntity.java:[60,30] package org.apache.ambari.view does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewInstanceEntity.java:[61,30] package org.apache.ambari.view does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewInstanceEntity.java:[62,30] package org.apache.ambari.view does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewInstanceEntity.java:[63,30] package org.apache.ambari.view does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewInstanceEntity.java:[64,40] package org.apache.ambari.view.migration does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewInstanceEntity.java:[65,40] package org.apache.ambari.view.migration does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewInstanceEntity.java:[66,41] package org.apache.ambari.view.validation does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewInstanceEntity.java:[67,41] package org.apache.ambari.view.validation does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewInstanceEntity.java:[99,44] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class ViewInstanceDefinition
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewInstanceEntity.java:[140,11] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ClusterType
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.orm.entities.ViewInstanceEntity
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewEntity.java:[47,30] package org.apache.ambari.view does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewEntity.java:[48,30] package org.apache.ambari.view does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewEntity.java:[49,41] package org.apache.ambari.view.validation does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewEntity.java:[58,36] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class ViewDefinition
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewInstanceEntity.java:[228,36] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ResourceProvider
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.orm.entities.ViewInstanceEntity
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewInstanceEntity.java:[248,11] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ViewDataMigrator
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.orm.entities.ViewInstanceEntity
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewInstanceEntity.java:[357,10] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ViewDefinition
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.orm.entities.ViewInstanceEntity
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewInstanceEntity.java:[469,10] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ClusterType
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.orm.entities.ViewInstanceEntity
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewInstanceEntity.java:[478,30] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ClusterType
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.orm.entities.ViewInstanceEntity
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewInstanceEntity.java:[744,55] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ResourceProvider
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.orm.entities.ViewInstanceEntity
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewInstanceEntity.java:[754,10] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ResourceProvider
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.orm.entities.ViewInstanceEntity
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewInstanceEntity.java:[764,10] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ResourceProvider
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.orm.entities.ViewInstanceEntity
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewInstanceEntity.java:[843,43] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ViewDataMigrationContext
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.orm.entities.ViewInstanceEntity
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewInstanceEntity.java:[843,10] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ViewDataMigrator
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.orm.entities.ViewInstanceEntity
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewInstanceEntity.java:[857,67] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ViewDataMigrator
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.orm.entities.ViewInstanceEntity
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewInstanceEntity.java:[858,57] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ViewContext
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.orm.entities.ViewInstanceEntity
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewInstanceEntity.java:[859,57] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ViewDataMigrationContext
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.orm.entities.ViewInstanceEntity
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewInstanceEntity.java:[857,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ViewDataMigrator
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.orm.entities.ViewInstanceEntity
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewInstanceEntity.java:[880,56] package Validator does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewInstanceEntity.java:[895,91] package Validator does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/view/validation/InstanceValidationResultImpl.java:[23,41] package org.apache.ambari.view.validation does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/view/validation/ValidationResultImpl.java:[21,41] package org.apache.ambari.view.validation does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/view/validation/ValidationResultImpl.java:[26,46] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class ValidationResult
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/view/configuration/ViewConfig.java:[31,30] package org.apache.ambari.view does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/view/configuration/ViewConfig.java:[32,30] package org.apache.ambari.view does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/view/configuration/ViewConfig.java:[33,40] package org.apache.ambari.view.migration does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/view/configuration/ViewConfig.java:[34,41] package org.apache.ambari.view.validation does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/view/configuration/ResourceConfig.java:[29,30] package org.apache.ambari.view does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewEntity.java:[223,11] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class View
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.orm.entities.ViewEntity
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewEntity.java:[229,11] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Validator
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.orm.entities.ViewEntity
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewEntity.java:[235,11] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ViewStatus
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.orm.entities.ViewEntity
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewEntity.java:[324,10] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ViewStatus
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.orm.entities.ViewEntity
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewEntity.java:[765,23] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class View
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.orm.entities.ViewEntity
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewEntity.java:[774,10] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class View
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.orm.entities.ViewEntity
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewEntity.java:[783,28] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Validator
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.orm.entities.ViewEntity
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewEntity.java:[792,10] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Validator
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.orm.entities.ViewEntity
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/orm/entities/ViewEntity.java:[855,25] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ViewStatus
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.orm.entities.ViewEntity
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/view/validation/InstanceValidationResultImpl.java:[41,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ValidationResult
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.view.validation.InstanceValidationResultImpl
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/view/validation/InstanceValidationResultImpl.java:[52,39] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ValidationResult
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.view.validation.InstanceValidationResultImpl
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/view/validation/InstanceValidationResultImpl.java:[52,84] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ValidationResult
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.view.validation.InstanceValidationResultImpl
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/view/validation/InstanceValidationResultImpl.java:[65,22] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ValidationResult
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.view.validation.InstanceValidationResultImpl
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/view/validation/InstanceValidationResultImpl.java:[82,34] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ValidationResult
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.view.validation.InstanceValidationResultImpl
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/view/validation/InstanceValidationResultImpl.java:[82,79] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ValidationResult
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.view.validation.InstanceValidationResultImpl
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/view/validation/InstanceValidationResultImpl.java:[96,35] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ValidationResult
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.view.validation.InstanceValidationResultImpl
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/view/validation/InstanceValidationResultImpl.java:[96,80] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ValidationResult
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.view.validation.InstanceValidationResultImpl
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/view/validation/ValidationResultImpl.java:[74,41] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ValidationResult
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.view.validation.ValidationResultImpl
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/view/validation/ValidationResultImpl.java:[74,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ValidationResult
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.view.validation.ValidationResultImpl
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/view/configuration/ViewConfig.java:[111,27] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class View
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.view.configuration.ViewConfig
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/view/configuration/ViewConfig.java:[134,27] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ViewDataMigrator
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.view.configuration.ViewConfig
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/view/configuration/ViewConfig.java:[145,27] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Validator
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.view.configuration.ViewConfig
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/view/configuration/ViewConfig.java:[156,27] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Masker
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.view.configuration.ViewConfig
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/view/configuration/ViewConfig.java:[312,26] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class View
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.view.configuration.ViewConfig
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/view/configuration/ViewConfig.java:[337,26] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ViewDataMigrator
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.view.configuration.ViewConfig
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/view/configuration/ViewConfig.java:[371,26] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Validator
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.view.configuration.ViewConfig
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/view/configuration/ViewConfig.java:[395,26] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Masker
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.view.configuration.ViewConfig
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/view/configuration/ResourceConfig.java:[74,27] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ResourceProvider
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.view.configuration.ResourceConfig
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/view/configuration/ResourceConfig.java:[170,26] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ResourceProvider
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.view.configuration.ResourceConfig
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/api/services/LogoutService.java:[27,37] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ApiIgnore
[ERROR]   location: package org.apache.ambari.annotations
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/api/services/RepositoryService.java:[34,37] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ApiIgnore
[ERROR]   location: package org.apache.ambari.annotations
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/api/services/UpgradeGroupService.java:[32,37] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ApiIgnore
[ERROR]   location: package org.apache.ambari.annotations
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/api/services/UpgradeItemService.java:[33,37] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ApiIgnore
[ERROR]   location: package org.apache.ambari.annotations
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/api/services/TaskService.java:[33,37] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ApiIgnore
[ERROR]   location: package org.apache.ambari.annotations
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/controller/ViewInstanceResponse.java:[28,30] package org.apache.ambari.view does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/controller/ViewInstanceResponse.java:[29,41] package org.apache.ambari.view.validation does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/controller/ViewInstanceRequest.java:[28,30] package org.apache.ambari.view does not exist
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/controller/ViewInstanceResponse.java:[53,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ValidationResult
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.controller.ViewInstanceResponse.ViewInstanceResponseInfo
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/controller/ViewInstanceResponse.java:[54,25] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ValidationResult
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.controller.ViewInstanceResponse.ViewInstanceResponseInfo
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/controller/ViewInstanceResponse.java:[75,94] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ClusterType
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.controller.ViewInstanceResponse.ViewInstanceResponseInfo
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/controller/ViewInstanceResponse.java:[169,12] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ValidationResult
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.controller.ViewInstanceResponse.ViewInstanceResponseInfo
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/controller/ViewInstanceResponse.java:[177,37] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ValidationResult
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.controller.ViewInstanceResponse.ViewInstanceResponseInfo
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/controller/ViewInstanceResponse.java:[186,24] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ValidationResult
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.controller.ViewInstanceResponse.ViewInstanceResponseInfo
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/controller/ViewInstanceResponse.java:[194,58] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ValidationResult
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.controller.ViewInstanceResponse.ViewInstanceResponseInfo
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/controller/ViewInstanceRequest.java:[70,19] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ClusterType
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.controller.ViewInstanceRequest.ViewInstanceRequestInfo
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/controller/ViewInstanceRequest.java:[89,93] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ClusterType
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.controller.ViewInstanceRequest.ViewInstanceRequestInfo
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/controller/ViewInstanceRequest.java:[208,12] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ClusterType
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.ambari.server.controller.ViewInstanceRequest.ViewInstanceRequestInfo
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/api/services/WidgetService.java:[35,37] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ApiIgnore
[ERROR]   location: package org.apache.ambari.annotations
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/api/services/views/ViewPermissionService.java:[37,37] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ApiIgnore
[ERROR]   location: package org.apache.ambari.annotations
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/api/services/HostComponentService.java:[42,37] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ApiIgnore
[ERROR]   location: package org.apache.ambari.annotations
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/api/services/HostComponentService.java:[43,37] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class SwaggerPreferredParent
[ERROR]   location: package org.apache.ambari.annotations
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/api/services/HostComponentService.java:[65,2] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class SwaggerPreferredParent
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/api/services/HostKerberosIdentityService.java:[35,37] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ApiIgnore
[ERROR]   location: package org.apache.ambari.annotations
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/api/services/HostStackVersionService.java:[33,37] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ApiIgnore
[ERROR]   location: package org.apache.ambari.annotations
[ERROR] /usr/local/apache-ambari-2.7.6-src/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/api/services/RepositoryVersionService.java:[35,37] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ApiIgnore
[ERROR]   location: package org.apache.ambari.annotations
```

Any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

@LMK There are several instance of this question/post.   A complete example of one is:

[Ambari 2.7.5 installation failure on CentOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61542102/ambari-2-7-5-installation-failure-on-centos-7)

I would recommend that you read through that, and look for the others.  You are going to need to apply the lessons learned.   Its been a long time since i did this, but TL;DR:  you need to get the right versions of maven as well as having your build environment and operating system setup as close as possible to the command flow i posted above.